# My css style it's not showing up, nodejs, express, hbs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I've made this sample code, but first let me show you my folder struture.

```
---public
-----css
------style.css
---views
-----video.hbs
-----video2.hbs
---server.js
```

this is my server code.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const hbs = require('hbs');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

//Express hbs engine 
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/parciales');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/video', (req, res) => {
    res.render('video.hbs');
});
app.get('/video/2', (req, res) => {
    res.render('video2.hbs');
});
app.listen(port, () => {})
```

Now the problem is the next... When I got to localhost:8080/video my css is working fine but when I goin to /video/2 my css it's not showing up, any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably importing your CSS as `./css/style.css`. You need to import it as `/css/style.css`.

Comment: happy to help :)